# Alguem me pode ajudar neste exercicio matlab

Tags: matlab

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem me pode ajudar neste exercicio matlab. É a alinea B.

Eu fiz assim mas não consegui perceber porque é que esta mal. Podias explicar-me porque é que está errrado?

```
function [i120, m120] = func11(mat)

i120 = 0;

m120 = 0;

for i = 1 : size(mat,1)

[ival,mval] = func10(mat(i,:),120)

i120 = i120 + 1;

m120 = m120 + 1;

end
```

A partir daqui já não consigo acabar o código, pois não estou a ver como é que consigo implementar a função anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso, o enunciado solicita que a função anterior seja utilizada. Assim, o melhor caminho é iterar pelas linhas. Geralmente, com MATLAB é melhor aproveitar a capacidade de usar vetorização. De qualquer modo, segue uma possível solução conforme o enunciado:

```
function [nIgualTotal, nMaiorTotal] = func11(mat)
     nLinhas = size(mat);
     nIgualTotal = 0;
     nMaiorTotal = 0;
     limite = 120;

     for i = 1:nLinhas(1)

         [nIgual, nMaior] = func10(mat(i,:), limite);

         nIgualTotal = nIgualTotal+nIgual;
         nMaiorTotal = nMaiorTotal+nMaior;
     end

end
```

Alternativamente, o código vetorizado poderia se parecer com algo tipo:

```
function [nIgualTotal, nMaiorTotal] = func11(mat)

limite = 120;

nIgualTotal = numel(mat(mat == limite));

nMaiorTotal = numel(mat(mat > limite));


end
```